# Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I receive this error,

```
 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
```

in this lines of code. Any how to fix it?

```
   for (; index < nPageFullItemCnt; index++) {
        strIndex = "0" + index;
        keyIndex = "popup_item_" + strIndex.substr(strIndex.length - 2, 2);
        keyItem = document.getElementById(keyIndex);

        setPopupKeyText(keyIndex, " ");

        keyItem.className = "popupLangItemNone";
        keyItem.langId = "";
    }
```

Comment: What line number does it say, and what are the previous lines of your code?

Comment: The error isn't happening within this code block. You need to share more code.

Comment: You have to know that JSLint is a very strict code quality tool that makes errors of what isn't really a big deal. Try using [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) instead, it's more merciful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing in the first parameter to the `for()` loop:

```
for (index = 0; index < nPageFullItemCnt; index++) 
{
    /* .. */
}
```

Comment: Only if the variable `index` is defined somewhere.

Comment: yes it is defined in another part of code, probably jslit does not like it

Comment: It could be related to scoping I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

This bit:

```
for (; index
```

Is causing that error. The code should validate if you do this:

```
for (0; index
```

(As I assume you're not passing the first parameter, on purpose)

However, I'd suggest using a `while` loop, instead of a for, if you're not going to make use of the [`[initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax) properties in a `for` loop.

```
while(index < nPageFullItemCnt){
    // Do stuff;
    index++;
}
```

Technically, the 3 parameters are all optional, but some code validators can throw a error if they're missing.